# Paypal Sandbox - Internal Service Error

Tags: paypal, payment

I'm trying to hook up Paypal payments using Paypal Pro.

I'm trying to use the sandbox ( although we have a valid Pro account for live payments ) and I keep getting the 'Internal Service Error' this happens when using the form and also the checkout button.

I've validated the endpoints are correct ( if not it returns another error ) but it seems as if it's a problem with the account itself?

Can anybody point me in the right direction with this? Has anybody set this up themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Website payments pro wasn't active on the account and thus always returned the above error.